# Download all JAVA updates per version

Tags: java

Gentlemen, I need to download all updates of a specific version of Java Runtime Environment (ie, I need to download, jre6u1, jre6u2.....jre6u37, etc), I order to test different versions on a deployment.  Any suggestions on how to do a batch download of these?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have no choice but to go the [Java Archive](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html) and download them manually.

You could try to use a plugin like [Metalink Downloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/metalink-downloader/jnpljlobbiggcdikagmiepniibjdinap) for Google Chrome or [DownloadThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) for Firefox.